# prettier make my short lines longer

Tags: prettier

Is there any option in prettier that will disable that behavior when I have well-formatted by hands multi-line code that will fit in 80 characters and will be properly-formatted in one line but will looks ugly. 
I want to keep it as is.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, as Prettier will rewrite the whole thing. It's also going to be hard to recognise if it was the intended behaviour or not, as Prettier fixes other issues as well.